# Power Series Property Examples

Tags: real-analysis

Could anyone help me with the following question:

For the following, find a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ with the given property or explain why it is impossible.

1. converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ - *Take $4a_n=0$ for all $n$, then series converges.*
2. diverges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ - *Impossible... since if $x=0$, the series diverges regardless of $(a_n)$.*
3. converges at $x=1$ and diverges at $x=-1$ - *I couldn't think of an answer*
4. converges absolutely at $x=1$ and diverges at $x=-1$ - *I couldn't think of an answer*

Comment: Write your question properly using Dollar.

Comment: (2) is correct, except that it should say 'converges regardless ...'. For (3) you can take $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n}$. For (3) if the series converges absolutely for $x=1$ it does so for $x=-1$, since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n||x|^n$ is the same series for $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to 1) and 2) are good. Hint for 3): Alternating series. 4) Note $|a_n\cdot (-1)^n| = |a_n\cdot1^n|.$